# The Method of Distribution Functions, what is the pdf of g(X1, X2,..., Xn)?

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics

This problem actually has a solution in below

[image]

I am just curious how does the first line after "so that" get into the second line.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy. The first line is $F_Y(y)$. It's derivative is $f_Y(y)$ and whatever one does to the left hand side of the equation, one does to the right hand as well. To take the derivative of an integral with a variable lower limit and a constant upper limit, the constant is dropped and that derivative is merely the negative of the derivative of an integral with a variable upper limit, which is then the chain rule derivative of that variable limit times the unchanged inside of the integral.

BTW, the chain rule differentiation of an integral is called the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), and see that link for a more extensive, symbolic presentation of this.